# She bound up his wounds. (What's the meaning of 'up'?)

Tags: adverbs, phrasal-verbs

> She bound up his wounds.

As I know we don't need 'up' here to mean the same meaning of the senence above.

What's the meaning of 'up' here?

Answer (score 1):

There are hundreds of instances in English where a preposition is tacked on to a verb to change the verb’s meaning.

- turn up
- dance around
- piss off
- hit on
- run through

If you “bind” something, you attach it to something else.  If you “bind up” something, you wrap it with string, tape, or (in the case of a wound) bandages.

Comment: 'up' means that the person wrapping something making the wrapping upwards?

Comment: @BEBYGONES no. It’s just two words that together have a specific meaning. Think of the expression „wind up“ for a toy or ball of yarn. Neither is necessarily going upwards, it simply means „coil“. If someone is „dolled up“, they are wearing formal attire or are ostentatiously dressed. There are plenty of such combinations and “up” doesn’t necessarily imply “upwards” in a directional sense.

Comment: @Stephie You mean not necessarily mean 'upwards' but could also mean 'upwards'?

Comment: @BEBYGONES It’s safer to assume that there’s no direction implied. Of course one could (weakly) argue that if you „truss up“ a turkey you are binding the legs somewhat “up” towards the body, but that’s not what matters, it’s the “binding everything together”. As does “dolled up” not imply putting a woman’s hair up in a bun or other hairdo. So assume “no” and treat any upward element as coincidence rather than intention.

Comment: @Stephie, what's with the weird „up-and-down“ quote marks?

Comment: @MichaelHarvey Mobile phone + switching languages halfway through. I think the message was received nevertheless and the comments will be deleted at some point anyway.

Answer (score 1):

'Bind up' is a compositional phrasal verb combining a verb ('bind') and a particle ('up'). In this type of verb, the particle adds an extra meaning to the verb. The particle 'up' is often used to add the extra meaning of 'to maximal effect'. If a piece of paper is torn, it might just have a tear in one place, and be otherwise complete, but if it is torn up, then it is torn into a number of separate pieces, and the implication is that it is ruined, spoiled, no longer useful. If we say a wound is bound up, then we are saying that it is so completely wrapped in e.g. bandages or cloth, etc, that it is properly covered so that it can heal properly.

> it can be argued that compositional phrasal verbs (e.g., drink up the
> milk, wipe down the countertop) can be derived from the combined
> meanings of the particle and the verb.  That is, compositional phrasal
> verbs merely add an aspectual element to the simple verb, and particle
> usage might be better analyzed as a property of the simple verb.

[Compositional phrasal verbs with up: Direction, aspect, intensity: Peter Machonis (Lingvisticae Investigationes, 2009)](https://hal.archives-ouvertes.fr/hal-01016670/document)